# Disable screen capture wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a security related windows phone application. I need to disable/block screen capture for my application.

In Android, we used to set a flag `FLAG_SECURE` to the window of which we want to block the screen capture. Is there anything similar in wp7 also??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's currently no API available to developers that allows you to perform screen captures with a **locked device**.

The alternatives are as follows:

1. Unlock your device and sideload one of the homebrew based screen
   capture apps.
2. Take a picture of the screen itself (Crude but it
   would do the job).

Microsoft have stated that they do not intend to change this in the near future [(CNET Article)](http://news.cnet.com/8301-10805_3-20028597-75.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can't do screen captures on Windows Phone unless you use homebrew apps, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

And even if there were screen capture apps on the marketplace, you would have no way to be safe. Even if you found a way to prevent screen captures, how would you prevent users from taking a picture of the phone with a camera, or sideloading the app on the emulator then making screen captures of the emulator?

Comment: we can't do screen captures on locked Windows Phone?

Comment: It may change in the future, but today it isn't possible on a locked phone.